# Convergence in distribution of a sequence of random variables. (Related to the birthday problem)

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I have been presented with the following problem:

> Let $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ be independent and identically distributed uniform random variables on the set {$1, 2, ... , n$}. Define $X^{(n)} = $min{$k : Y_k = Y_j$ for some  $j<k$}. Prove that $X^{(n)}/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to a limit with distribution function $F(x) = 1 - $exp$(-x^2/2)$ for $x>0$.

Now I realise that $\mathbb{P}(X^{(n)}>m) = (1-1/n)(1-2/n)...(1-(m-1)/n)$, but I am having trouble showing that this converges in distribution with the square root $n$ involved. Any help would be great!

Comment: Hint: Take the $\log$  of $\Bbb P(X^{(n)}>m)$, thereby converting a product into a sum; use the Taylor approximation $\log(1-u) = -u-u^2/2+o(u^2)$ to then get an idea of how $\log\Bbb P(X^{(n)}>\sqrt{n}\,m)$ behaves for large $n$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins How does applying the bound to $\mathbb{P}(X^{(n)}>m)$ give and idea of how $\mathbb{P}(X^{(n)}>\sqrt{n}m)$ behaves?

Comment: I get that $\log{\mathbb{P}(X^{(n)}>m)} = \log{(1-1/n)} + ... + \log{(1-(m-1)/n)} \Rightarrow \frac{1-m}{n} + (\frac{1-m}{n})^2 < \log{\mathbb{P}(X^{(n)}>m)} < \frac{1-m}{n}$ and from this $$e^{-1/n - (1-m)/n^2)} < \mathbb{P}(X^{(n)}>m) < e^{(-1/n)}$$, which then implies that $\mathbb{P}(X^{(n)}>m) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. But I don't understand how to put the $\sqrt{n}$ into this bound.